# Simple UIScrollView in Swift2

Tags: swift, uiscrollview

Im trying to implement a scrollView, pythoScroll, into my code! It runs but then i get runtime error and this message appears... "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" and it points to these two lines inside my viewDidLoad.
Thank you

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    pythoScroll.contentSize.height = 100
    pythoScroll.contentSize.width = 300

}
```

Comment: pythoScroll is nil, probably not connected in Interface Builder

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Answer (score 0):

You can setup your scroll view programmatically. It's better and neater in my opinion. To do so:

1. Create a ScrollView variable just before your viewDidLoad()

   `var scrollView = UIScrollView!`
2. Inside your viewDidLoad() do the following:

   `scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: view.bounds)
   scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 300, height: 300)
   view.addSubview(scrollView)`
3. That's pretty much it. To be honest I'm not on Xcode so I can't really test whether this code runs or not. Try it out, and if there are any issues let me know.

Comment: Why initialize two scroll views?